# Subdomain preserves cookies from main domain

Tags: apache, cookies, prestashop

I've set a cookie banner for a `domain.com`. It's a plugin for CMS. It works with user consent - blocking or giving permission to load a `GTM` script.

And I have an e-shop based on `PrestaShop` with a cookie banner plugin, which works with the same logic.

e-shop is placed on a `subdomain.domain.com`.

*The problem*: once a user grants consent on `domain.com` `GTM` cookies are loaded, the user clicks on a button leading to `subdomain.domain.com` (e-shop) and all previous cookies are loaded. What is not a good behaviour for a GDPR

So, is there an easy way to clear previous cookies?

Prestashop runs on Apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent):

> Domain attribute
>
> The Domain attribute specifies which hosts can receive a cookie. If unspecified, the attribute defaults to the same host that set the cookie, excluding subdomains. If Domain is specified, then subdomains are always included. Therefore, specifying Domain is less restrictive than omitting it. However, it can be helpful when subdomains need to share information about a user.

When setting your cookies, omit the Domain attribute.

This will prevent future cookies being applied to the subdomains (and will overwrite the old ones which were on the next visit which sets them).

Comment: Thanks! Does the `SameSite: Lax/Strict` solves this or it's not related?

Comment: @Kuzma — It is unrelated. That handles cross-origin subrequests (e.g. if you were to put a page on `example.com` in an iframe on `example.net` you could say if the cookies for `example.com` should be sent or not).